# visual studio 2008 won't let me drag certain controls

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

group box, flow layout panel, panel, split container,and tab control do not drag.

I believe uninstalling resharper is when it started to happen.

I've done a repair on visual studio. I've uninstalled and reinstalled.

Any idea where I would look or what is wrong?

When I click on the drag icon. the mouse snaps left to the resize handle, and does not let me drag.

Comment: after the repair, when I uninstalled, I went through the documents and settings folders and deleted everything that was in a microsoft visual studio folder that I could find.

Comment: checking my visual studio at work now, and the mouse does a snap to the left just like at home, but while holding the mouse it starts the drag operation. So I confirmed that 1. I know how to drag the group box just fine (for those doubting). and 2. the problem is with my home copy, not with the work copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that somehow a mouse or mouse driver was causing this. When I brought my work machine home. the problem was suddenly on my work machine. When I shut it off, hooked up a different keyboard and mouse... the problem dissapeared. A few weeks back my mouse's 5th button broke. I'm guessing it broke in such a way that the button is held down, or other parts of it also messed up. because as long as that mouse doesn't get plugged in, my dragging in visual studio on those specific controls works. It was an old Razer mouse. When I went into the device manager, there was a conflict/warning showing on that mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any add-ins? Try deleting the ones you have enabled.

Comment: it started before I installed the DevExpress add on, I believe right after I uninstalled resharper. I'll uninstall it now.

Comment: Okay, let me know if that works. Also, since you appear to be good with vb, think you could help with one of my questions?

Comment: I'm pretty terrible compared to most the people on this forum, but I'll be glad to look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257637/setting-focus-on-datagridview-control-programmatically-in-visual-basic was my question

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working now. Maybe try uninstalling, and removing information in /Program Files/ related to it?

Comment: I didn't try removing all the /Program Files/ stuff.

Comment: I've done a full removal including all program files stuff in the microsoft visual studio folder, no improvement

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, try clearing all data saved, all of it.

Comment: I'm using windows XP SP3. what data saved?

Comment: The standard location for My.Settings. Just erase the XML config files there, or take backups just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to click anywhere on the control and drag?

In case of container controls, you can only click on the little box icon with 4 arrows on the top left and drag. Clicking anywhere else on the controls will not start the drag.

Comment: I've been using visual studio for almost 3 years now. the icon with 4 arrows is exactly what I'm clicking on, but it snaps left to a an upper left hand corner resize node.